# Neo4j-enterprise auto-scaling on Amazon ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, neo4j, amazon-ecs

I have a question in regards to Amazon ECS and experiences people might have with deploying a Neo4j-enterprise(3.x) within aws-ecs. With auto-scaling, load balancing and all the bells and whistles that would come with it.

If anyone have tried and hit a brick wall, then I wouldn't mind learning from their experience.

And we are looking for scaling both on cluster and on containers running inside of the cluster.